# how do i show a tooltip without focusing any element on intro.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, intro.js

i am using intro.js for my product tour. i want to show tooltip without focusing any element like "welcome to the XYZ tour". i want to use only bootstrap and intro js and i dont want to use any alerts,popups... any solution in terms of intro.js options here i am attaching screenshots.. i am able to attain it if i assing some random selector value, but i want a clean and fair code

coffee js:

intro.setOptions steps : [
        element : "randomXyzselectorThatDoesntExistinPage"
        intro : "Welcome to the Create New Booking Tour, please follow the step by step guide to understand the flow clearly

Click the ‘Next’ button to get started on the tour

"
        position : "bottom"
      ,
        element : ".userContainer"
        intro : "FIRST, lets Search if the Guest already exists in our records

Click the NEXT button to get started on the tour"
        position : "bottom"
      ,
        element : ".availabilityContainer"
        intro : "Now, lets Check the availability of  OYOs for the dates our Guest requires stay and choose one of the availble OYOs to proceed to book"
        position : "bottom"
      ,
        element : ".overlayIntrojs"
        intro : "After selecting an OYO among the available OYOs for those dates, lets choose number of rooms, type of rooms, extra beds, extra persons,discount and other basic information about the booking"
        position : "top"
      ,
        element : ".introJsSel4"
        intro : "The Payment Details section!, proceed to confirm the booking by entering payment details like mode of payment, amount paid, payment reference number etc"
        position : "top"
    ]
    intro.setOption "doneLabel", "Finish"
    intro.start().oncomplete ->
      window.location.href = "/admin/bookings/36"
      return

SCREENSHOT :

[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2zges2b.jpg[/IMG]

i want the first tooltip to be dispalyed as some WELCOME MESSAGE than direct tour slide...
i want what i show in the above image,without having to give some random selector in steps but in a clear introjs supported way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use programmatic definition of steps like following:

```
    var intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
          { 
            intro: "Hello world!"
          },
          { 
            intro: "You <b>don't need</b> to define element to focus, this is a floating tooltip."
          }
        ]
      });

      intro.start();
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/withoutElement/index.html